# OSX High Sierra - Files and Folders show as empty/invisible in Finder, but are still there

Tags: macos, permission, vpn, hacking, invisible-files

I am running the latest version of High Sierra.

Both my user Library/Application Support and main Library/Application Support are completely empty when opened in Finder (see screenshot).

I was asked to delete a configuration file for an app I use which was misbehaving (a security-related app–a VPN app), and discovered that I cannot view files in these directories.

Yet, when I reinstalled the app, its configuration was still in place, meaning most likely that those folders DO still have their contents (which I have seen before) but they are being hidden from me.

Also I might add two things:

1) When this started happening two days ago, not only was that one folder empty in Finder (but not in Terminal), but since then, NO new files/folders created show up in Finder, and

2) If I kill Finder, and restart it, some of the new files show up. But it all started with that one folder; other pre-existing files and folders were not invisible-ized.

How can I fix this, and is it a hack?  I am trying to run a VPN, after all.

[image: screenshot]

The results of running `cd ~/Library` and `\ls -alt', as requested (and run as root, just for the sake of it).

`root:/Users/myuser/Library |#\ls -alt
total 32
drwx------+ 561 myuser  staff  17952 Nov 19 00:00 Preferences
drwxr-xr-x   40 myuser  staff   1280 Nov 18 23:59 Safari
drwx------@  43 myuser  staff   1376 Nov 18 23:59 Cookies
drwxr-xr-x   30 myuser  staff    960 Nov 18 23:58 SyncedPreferences
drwx------+   7 myuser  staff    224 Nov 18 23:51 Spelling
drwxr-xr-x   11 myuser  staff    352 Nov 18 23:45 Assistant
drwx------+ 119 myuser  staff   3808 Nov 18 23:40 Application Support
drwxr-xr-x   13 myuser  staff    416 Nov 18 23:40 Keychains
drwx------+ 103 myuser  staff   3296 Nov 18 23:39 Caches
drwxr-xr-x    5 myuser  staff    160 Nov 18 23:34 Parallels
drwx------@  49 myuser  staff   1568 Nov 18 23:34 Saved Application State
drwxr-xr-x   10 myuser  staff    320 Nov 18 00:14 Passes
drwxr-xr-x@  66 myuser  staff   2112 Nov 17 15:20 Mobile Documents
drwxr-xr-x@  21 myuser  staff    672 Nov 15 23:58 Suggestions
drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 Nov 15 17:07 Google
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Nov 14 12:50 CoreFollowUp
drwx------   10 myuser  staff    320 Nov 12 09:51 IdentityServices
drwxr-xr-x   25 myuser  staff    800 Nov 12 09:50 Calendars
drwx------+ 122 myuser  staff   3904 Nov 12 09:50 Logs
drwxr-xr-x@ 101 myuser  staff   3232 Nov 12 09:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  207 myuser  staff   6624 Nov  8 10:01 Application Scripts
drwx------  239 myuser  staff   7648 Nov  8 10:01 Containers
drwx------   23 myuser  staff    736 Nov  8 10:01 Group Containers
drwxr-xr-x    2 myuser  staff     64 Nov  7 18:45 PhotoshopCrashes
drwxr-xr-x    6 myuser  staff    192 Oct 21 14:56 Keyboard
drwx------   20 myuser  staff    640 Oct 18 22:18 WebKit
drwxrwxrwx    4 myuser  staff    128 Oct 15 01:25 Tokyo Dawn Labs
drwx------@  90 myuser  staff   2880 Oct 11 02:09 .
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff     67 Oct 11 02:09 StickiesDatabase
drwx------+   4 myuser  staff    128 Sep 30 02:42 PreferencePanes
-rw-r--r--@   1 myuser  staff   6148 Sep 30 02:42 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Sep 27 15:49 com.apple.internal.ck
drwx------+   5 myuser  staff    160 Sep 27 13:57 Printers
drwx------@   6 myuser  staff    192 Sep 27 03:49 Mail
drwxr-xr-x@   2 myuser  staff     64 Sep 27 03:18 SafariSafeBrowsing
drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 Sep 27 01:53 Metadata
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Sep 27 01:50 FileProvider
drwx------    7 myuser  staff    224 Sep 27 01:50 Messages
drwx------    8 myuser  staff    256 Sep 27 01:50 Accounts
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Sep 27 01:50 Family
drwxr-xr-x   24 myuser  staff    768 Sep  6 15:40 SafariTechnologyPreview
drwx------    5 myuser  staff    160 Sep  1 19:01 Autosave Information
drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 Sep  1 18:56 Scripts
drwx------+  10 myuser  staff    320 Aug 27 04:51 FontCollections
drwx------+  19 myuser  staff    608 Aug 23 22:06 Fonts
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Aug 10 11:44 Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x    9 myuser  staff    288 Aug 10 11:44 LaunchAgents
drwxr-xr-x   20 myuser  staff    640 Jul 13 13:08 iTunes
drwxr-xr-x   18 myuser  staff    576 Jul 10 16:18 LanguageModeling
drwxr-xr-x    2 myuser  staff     64 Jul  7 16:46 QuickLook
drwx------    5 myuser  staff    160 Oct 25  2016 Personas
drwxr-xr-x    2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 23  2016 PDF Services
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 23  2016 Speech
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 23  2016 Workflows
drwxr-xr-x    5 myuser  staff    160 Oct 18  2016 KeyboardServices
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 18  2016 Maps
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 18  2016 CallServices
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 18  2016 Sharing
drwx------+   3 myuser  staff     96 Mar 22  2016 Internet Plug-Ins
drwxr-xr-x    6 myuser  staff    192 Mar 13  2016 Address Book Plug-Ins
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff    528 Jan  5  2016 ._bundleInfo
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Dec 26  2015 Polyverse
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Nov 23  2015 HipChat
drwx------    3 myuser  staff     96 Nov 15  2015 Saved Searches
drwxr-xr-x    5 myuser  staff    160 Nov  2  2015 PubSub
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Nov  2  2015 CoreData
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff      0 Nov  1  2015 .localized
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Jul  6  2015 A1AUDIO.de
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Jun  6  2015 Frameworks
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Jun  6  2015 Java
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Jun  6  2015 Python
drwx------+   8 myuser  staff    256 Jan 14  2015 Audio
drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 Jan  9  2015 Developer
drwx------    5 myuser  staff    160 Nov  7  2014 Social
drwx--x--x    2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 30  2014 GameKit
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 Twitter
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 ColorSync
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Assistants
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 ColorPickers
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Colors
drwx------+   3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 Compositions
drwx------+   3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 Favorites
drwx------+   3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 Input Methods
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Keyboard Layouts
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Screen Savers
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Services
drwx------@   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Sounds
drwx------+   2 myuser  staff     64 Oct 29  2014 Voices
drwx------+   4 myuser  staff    128 Oct 29  2014 iMovie
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Oct 29  2014 Dictionaries`

Comment: Now this has happened to my Downloads folder as well.  I think the machine may be hacked, and quite possibly rooted, since things like this tend to happen just before I need to do something (like delete a preference file to fix a VPN app).   Either way, how can I hack it back?

Comment: Can you view the files in Terminal?

Comment: @Allan great question.  Yes, I absolutely can see the files in the terminal, with a simple directory listing command.  So they are there (for now).

Comment: Can you go to these directories and get the permissions on them? For example, in the terminal, run `cd ~/Library` and do an `\ls -alt` and update your question with the far left column information. Mine is `drwx------+ USERNAME staff etc, etc`

Comment: @Jahhein yes, certainly.  Unfortunately, the list is too long to put in this comment, so I'll update the original question.

Comment: Another thing to try: `\ls -alO@ ~/Library/"Application Support"` will show file flags (such as "hidden") and extended attributes, if they exist.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good suggestion, but most people get freaked out by the com.apple.quarantine flag so I didn't suggest that. @rcd looks like your files have correct permissions. Might I suggest running `sudo diskutil repairPermissions / ` to fix permissions in case anything is needed. regarding Finder.app , this command `sudo find / -type f -name '*.DS_Store' -ls -delete` will remove all .DS_Store files (Finder's preference file per directory) and see if that might help?

Comment: Will get these results (extended attributes looked okay) but I'd love to hear about the quarantine flag.  Pretty sure this machine is rooted, since I was told it was rooted by the same guys who broke into my house, but it's some really high level stuff because these usual tricks aren't working.

Comment: @Jahhein I ran `diskutil repairPermissions /` and received this message: `diskutil: did not recognize verb "repairPermissions"; type "diskutil" for a list`.  How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

There has been a slight change in the command for High Sierra - It uses **'YES'** instead of **'true'**!

High Sierra:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Before:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to display all files and folders. To do so go to terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Then relaunch the Finder.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already done this.  The OS has been set to show all (and hidden) files since I first began using it (using the same defaults command).

Answer (score 2):

It is a truly annoying bug that will come up again and again.  Restart the finder fixes it, but it is past my ability to understand how said bug made its way to released software.